# Php returns always start with 0AH (line feed) character?

Tags: php

I'm always getting a `0AH` (line feed) character at the beginning of the PHP answer. For instance, a simple `echo $str` always starts with `0AH`. I'm using UTF-8 encoding and PHP 5.3. Does anyone have any idea about what can it be? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is really `0AH`, then it's most likely an enter before your `<?php` opening tag. Any content before the tag is outputted as-is.

Since you're using UTF8 encoding, maybe it's not an line feed after all but a UTF-8 BOM (Byte Order Mark). To solve that issue, make sure you save your files as *UTF-8 without BOM*.

Comment: Thanks Goled, it is solved now. I was having an enter character in the php script before the `<?php` tag and also after the closing tag. I have deleted both and now the server's answer is ok.